# By your negligence I may run, but faced with the choice, most would prefer to swim

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I'm the goal of sharks, who could surely fall,
>   If they once fail to make good on their call.
>
> On both your time and your waste I am quite a drain,
>   and when all else is taken, I will remain.
>
> I suck up heat but am cool while I thus feed,
>   And my boats house the fish that don't catch my lead.

What am I?

Hint:

> I'm one word, but many things

---

I'm posting this as a riddle, but also would appreciate feedback if you have any.

Comment: waste or waist, for clarification?

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Waste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are:

> Sink

By your negligence I may run, but faced with the choice, most would prefer to swim

> One can sink if one neglects to swim

I'm the goal of sharks, who could surely fall,
If they once fail to make good on their call.

> Sharks sink if they stop moving, apparently

On both your time and your waste I am quite a drain

> A sink is a drain for waste; and a time consuming activity is also called a "time drain" or [time sink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_sink)

and when all else is taken, I will remain

> As in "everything but the kitchen sink"

I suck up heat but am cool while I thus feed,

> A [heat sink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_sink)

And my boats house the fish that don't catch my lead.

> As in "falling hook, line and sinker"?

Comment: For the time clue, they probably wanted the expression "time [ answer ]"

Comment: All correct except the sharks, and kinda the last line. I'm not as happy with my wording of the last line though. It's more literal.

Comment: @ffao: Thanks, updated. @ HammerN'Songs: Sorry, I still don't have a lead on those and nothing else seems to be sinking in.

Comment: I forgot to update this; the last line is that ships that sink provide houses for fish, provided those fish haven't been caught (with a hook and sinker)

Answer (score 0):

It's more straightforward, but i think you are

> A Snake

By your negligence I may run, but faced with the choice, most would prefer to swim

> This snake could be a water snake. If a snake is approached it will most likely retreat unless cornered of attacked. They can also traverse land, but are most proficient at swimming.

Im the goal of sharks, who could surely fall,

> Snakes are great at catching food and defending themselves

If they once fail to make good on their call.

> If a shark is killed, they my wish they had the same hiding abilities as a snake

On both your time and your waste I am quite a drain,

> The poison can end your life, ending your time and the potential waste that you will produce in the future

and when all else is taken, I will remain.

> The snake is coiled up, when a small animal is taken by the snake, the snake then proceeds to coiling up again

I suck up heat but am cool while I thus feed,

> They spend their days in the sun to warm up, but during the night they hunt

And my boats house the fish that don't catch my lead.

> Humans may turn back from fishing if they find snakes in the water, so fish that are ahead of the snake are less likely to be caught